# Merging Two Lists Where one is a Sublist Created From Another List

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, nested-lists

True to the adage that weeks of programming will save you hours of work I started writing a little .py to backup my project files by going through all the network drives, locating a root project folder, having a look inside to see if there is a settings folder and if there is, to back it up off site.

I am firstly creating a list of the folders I am interested in:

```
Ant = "I:"
antD = os.listdir(Ant+'\\') 
# antD is the list of all stuff on ANT's D:\
antDpath = (Ant+'\\') 
namingRegex = re.compile( r"\d\d\d\d_\w[^.]*$")
# the above regex returns all folders that begin with four digits
# and a _ but do not contain a . so as not to include files
toCopyAnt = filter(namingRegex.match, antD) 
#List of folders to look in
```

So there I have a nice list of folders I am interested in in this form:

```
>>>toCopyAnt
['9001_Project44_IDSF', '5015_Project0_517', '8012_Project_whatever']
```

Next up I go on and make this mess:

```
inAnt = []
for i in range(len(toCopyAnt)):
    dirAnt = (antDpath+toCopyAnt[i])
    inAnt.append(dirAnt)
```

This part above is merely to add '\' to the list so that when os.dirlist below scans the directories I get proper output

```
antList = []
for i in range(len(toCopyAnt)):
    antL = os.listdir(inAnt[i])
    antList.append(antL)
```

This part here goes through each of the directories I have narrowed down and lists the contents.

The list `antList` looks like this:

```
>>>antList
    [['Data', 'MagicStuff', 'Info', 'settings'], ['Data', 'processing', 'Settings', 'modularTakeOff'], ['Blue_CCheese', 'Data', 'Rubbishbin', 'songBird', 'images', 'Settings', 'Cakes'], ['canDelete', 'Backup']]
```

it is a list of some lists... ugh.

My aim it to join these two fellas together such that I have another list which gives me the full path names for each sub directory like so in the case of toCopyAnt[2] and antList[2]

```
['I:\8012_Project_whatever\canDelete','I:\8012_Project_whatever\Backup']
```

With the final goal being to use this new list, remove strings I don't need and then parse that to tree_copy to make my life better in every way.

I figure there is likely a far more efficient way to do this and I would love to know but at the same time I would also like to tackle this issue as I have outlined it as it would increase my yield of lists greatly, I've only been at this python stuff for a few days now so I haven't got all the tools out the box just yet.

If what I am doing here is as painful and laboured as I suspect it is please point me in the right direction and I'll start over.

Ngiyabonga! 
Ingwe

**###########NEXT DAY EDIT###########**

So I slept on this and have been attacking the logic again. Still convinced that this is messy and clumsy but I must soldier on.

Below is the first part of what I had working last night with some differenct coments:

```
inant = []
for i in range(len(toCopyAnt)):
    dirant = (Ant+'\\'+toCopyAnt[i])   ##makes full path of higher folder
    inant.append(dirant)

antList = []
for i in range(len(toCopyAnt)):
    antL = os.listdir(inant[i])   ##provides names of all subfolders
    antList.append(antL)

for i in range(len(antList)):
    antList[i] = filter(settingRegex.match, antList[i])   ##filters out only inpho project folders


## This mess here next builds a list of full path folders to backup. 
preAntpath = []
postAntpath = []
for i in range(len(inant)):
    try:
        preAntpath=("%s\\%s\\"%(inant[i],antList[i][0]))
        postAntpath.append(preAntpath)
        preAntpath=("%s\\%s\\"%(inant[i],antList[i][1]))
        postAntpath.append(preAntpath)
        preAntpath=("%s\\%s\\"%(inant[i],antList[i][2]))
        postAntpath.append(preAntpath)
        preAntpath=("%s\\%s\\"%(inant[i],antList[i][3]))
        postAntpath.append(preAntpath)
    except:
        pass
```

Ok, so the reason there is 4 iterations is to just make sure that I include the backup copies of the folders I want to keep. Sometimes there is a 'settings' and a 'settings - copy'. I want both.

```
##
##
## some debuggering next...

for i in range(len(postAntpath)):
    print postAntpath[i]
```

It works. I get a new list with merged data from the two lists.
so where `inant[x]` and `antList[x]` match (because they are always the same length) `antList[x]` will merge with `inant[x][0-3]`.

If, as is often the case, there is no settings folder in the project folder the `try:` seems to take care of it. Although I will need to test some situations where the project folder is 1st or 2nd in the list. In my current case it is last. I don't know if `try:` tries each iteration or stops when it hits the first error...

So that is how I made my two list (one with list in a list) a single usable list.

Next up is to try and figure out how to copy the settings folder as is and not just all of its contents. Copytree is driving me mad.

Again, any comments or advice would be welcome.

Ingwe.